# sshd on a minimal Linux: "Failed password for invalid user root"

Tags: ssh, authentication, fedora, passwd

I'm trying to start SSH server on a minimal Fedora installation. And I mean really minimal: one that is produced by [diskimage-builder](https://github.com/openstack/diskimage-builder) ramdisk builder. It does not even have users (absent `/etc/passwd` etc).

So, now I'm trying to run sshd on such a system. During the build I copy `/etc/`{`passwd`,`group`,`shadow`} from a minimal (hmm.. less minimal) system. I also pregenerate host keys and `sshd_config`:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
UsePAM no
UseDNS no
UsePrivilegeSeparation no
PasswordAuthentication yes
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
```

([full script](https://github.com/divius/instack-undercloud/blob/ssh-ramdisk/elements/ironic-discoverd-ramdisk-ssh/ramdisk-install.d/90-setup-sshd)). In the ramdisk I set root password via chpasswd and start SSHd with

```
/sbin/sshd -p $SSH_PORT
```

(`SSH_PORT` being 22 for now - default one). And after the ramdisk boots and reports back, I try to log in. Here fun starts:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@192.0.2.114's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
Permission denied, please try again.
root@192.0.2.114's password:
```

In ssh logs on a server I see

```
debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method password
Could not get shadow information for NOUSER
Failed password for invalid user root from 192.0.2.1 port 38734 ssh2
```

So despite everything I tried, user '`root`' stays invalid. Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you didn't see this comment in the default `sshd_config` file?

```
# WARNING: 'UsePAM no' is not supported in Fedora and may cause several
# problems.
```

On Fedora and Red Hat, you must enable PAM authentication.

Comment: There's no PAM on these ramdisks. Also "cause several problems" does not mean "ok, we broke everything in a strange way" to me...

Comment: Well, that certainly explains why you can't authenticate.

Comment: sorry, but that does not. There was authentication in Unix much before PAM was invented. And presence of UsePAM=no option definitely says that sshd should work without it somehow...

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you must have solved your problem long time ago by now?

I have the same type of setup but on Debian, not Fedora, minimal linux no PAM etc and stumbled on this problem. google wasn't helpful, after downloading open SSH sources I found that sshd, in absence of PAM uses a glibc function, `getpwnam()`, in the authentication process. This function, no doubt, is super generic and helpful in any type of environment but it would not resort to checking the `/etc/passwd` and friends if `libnss_files.so.*` wasn't installed.

Adding this library to my minimal linux fixed the problem for me. I'm curious to know the reason in your case?